# What could possibly break an app during update through the iOS App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I am facing a very strange and extremely difficult to fix issue with an iPad app we have in the App Store. The reports, that the app doesn't work anymore after a new version has been rolled out, have multiplied over the last couple of weeks. Now I was able to reproduce the issue on an internal new iPad that had been restored from a backup with an older version and then updated through the normal App Store procedures.

The problem: while the application works fine if freshly installed through the App Store or run through XCode, it simply doesn't work as expected after the update. Once the app is in the "broken" state though, I can't even install a new version through XCode that works. Which in this case could be a good thing as it will help me to hopefully fix this issue.

What we have:

- the app has a set of `UIWebView`s that load content from a webpage.
- the webpage loads a Javascript framework and creates a global object `h5` which can be used to call methods inside it.
- from here on the communication App -> UIWebView is done through [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString] calls on this `h5` object.

And here comes the issue:

- the html is set in the UIWebView fine, but the JavaScript doesn't seem to get executed if the app is updated.
- I can run javascript stuff through [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString] and I am able to retrieve the rendered `outerHTML` this way just to find out that my `<script>` stuff is missing and thus not executed.

Needless to say that if I do a clean install either through the app store or XCode, the app runs fine, the JavaScript is executed and there are no problems.

What I tried so far:

- we use the Three20 library for some of our functionality and it has a cache. This cache has been cleared and checked whether or not it's really cleared.
- I deleted everything in `<Application root>/Library/caches`
- Instead of loading the URL through a separate request and then pushing it to the WebView through `[webView loadData]` I tried to

  - load the URL directly from the webserver with `[webView loadRequest]`
  - convert the `NSData` to a `NSString` and push that through `[webView loadHTMLString]`
  - have a `NSString` hold the html and push that through `[webView loadHTMLString]` without the need of loading the stuff remotely.

I am a bit out of further ideas what could be the cause here and I'd like to get your opinion on this issue. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Up front I can say I have no idea why your particular system isn't working.  However I can offer some advice that I hope is useful.

From what you have said, I understand that:

1. Version A of the App works
2. A clean install of Version B of the App works
3. Installing Version B over the top of Version A hoses the App.

To me this is indicative of something being left behind from Version A that is interfering with Version B - such as an old file located in a path that takes precedence over a newer file.

I know you said that you cleaned the caches, but are there other places in the system where you have stored away data that is not being cleaned out?

So in general I'd suggest doing some deep forensics of the App to trace the name and location of all assets from each version and ensure that they can be accounted for.

The good thing is that when you hose the App that it is permanent.  That sort of bug is easier to locate than something that happens "sometimes".

Comment: Do you have any idea where some other places could be? I found some files in `<Application root>/Library/Caches` and cleared that out (seems to clear Three20's cache as well. This should be all the places where the app directly or indirectly (some stuff obviously gets written by iOS automatically) creates files AFAIK. Just to be sure I also checked various other folders (documents, applicaiton support, downloads) for files that might give me a hint, but found nothing. Is there a way to list ALL files that are related to my app?

Comment: @mwidmann I'm sorry but I have no specific knowledge that could help you.  While I'm an iOS newbie myself, I was giving general advice based on a lifetime career of fault-finding software systems.  BTW the  listing files that belong to an App sounds like a great SO question!

Answer (score 0):

A few more assets to check:

Check the capitalization of all your file names (images, HTML, CSS, etc.), plist items and settings.

Check all NSDefaults saved/loaded and check for valid values for all app versions.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this very same issue last year right after they added the new data import/export tools in Xcode! The best way to repro and debug the problem is to install the older version export the data using the data export tool in Xcode's organizer, then build and go with Xcode to install the newer version. Next, stop the app, import the data you exported before, then build/go from Xcode to try to recreate the crash. If you're lucky like I was, gdb/lldb will stop on the error revealing the source of the problem. You can also try a brute force approach of releasing a new version which deletes all the data from the prior version but that would potentially leave a LOT of unhappy users.

Answer (score 0):

I have an update on this issue. I was able to remove the issue, but sadly I'm not 100% sure which of the files I deleted, was the source of the problem. Nevertheless I wanted to share my approach.

I was pretty sure that the problem must reside somewhere in the application folder as otherwise it wouldn't happen that the app works after a clean install, but doesn't when updated.

I decided to compare the file system inside my app when doing a clean install or with this broken version after the update. I decided to iterate over the application's folders and print out the files. Before and after clearing the cache. I added the following code to my `AppDelegate` to compare:

```
NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSApplicationDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSAutosavedInformationDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSDesktopDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSCachesDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSApplicationSupportDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSDownloadsDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSInputMethodsDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSMoviesDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSMusicDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSPicturesDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSPrinterDescriptionDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSSharedPublicDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSPreferencePanesDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSItemReplacementDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSAllApplicationsDirectory], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:NSAllLibrariesDirectory], 
                        nil];

NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
for ( NSNumber *directory in paths ) {
    NSArray *tp = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains([directory unsignedIntegerValue] , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    if ( [tp count] == 0 )
        continue;

    NSString *path = [tp objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [manager enumeratorAtPath:path];
    NSString *filename;

    NSLog(@"-------------------------------------------------------");
    NSLog(@"== path: %@", path);
    NSLog(@"-------------------------------------------------------");

    while ( filename = [direnum nextObject] ) {
        NSString *thefile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", path, filename];
        NSLog( @"\t%@, deletable? %d", filename, [manager isDeletableFileAtPath:thefile] );
    }

}
```

I then compared the output and found out that the only files left resided in `NSAllLibrariesDirectory`. Namely they were

```
Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
Preferences/com.apple.PeoplePicker.plist
Preferences/com.medienhaus.VOL.plist
```

Here I failed epically and implemented the clearing method to delete the files instead of going on one by one to figure out which file caused the problem.

So now I have a working version, but I don't know exactly which of those four files broke it. Most probable is `Cookies.binarycookies`.